# ping -a sometimes returns host name and sometimes returns FQDN. Why? Does this mean DNS is corrupt somehow?

Tags: domain-name-system, ping, tcpip, reverse-dns

I have a Windows machine called `abcd` for example and it uses DHCP to receive an IP address (`172.28.45.5` for example)

When I perform `ping -a 172.28.45.5` sometimes I receive `abcd` as the hostname. Sometimes I receive the FQDN, for example `abcd.xxx.yyy.com`, which is the preferred and accurate way.

Why do I receive the hostname sometimes, and the FQDN other times? Is this a sign of DNS being corrupt in some way?

Comment: Is the zone your host is in a Active Directory hosted zone?

Comment: Also, will you get the same sketchy results if you use `nslookup 172.28.45.5` multiple times? How many DNS servers are in your environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ping` is not a name resolution tool. It's an ICMP tool that has some DNS wonkery tacked on. When using `ping` as a name resolution troubleshooting tool on a Windows machine you're going to be batted around between responses from NetBIOS, potentially WINS, the hosts file, resolver cache, and (if you're lucky) a DNS server. Your mileage may vary, contents may settle during shipping, product sold by weight not volume, and photo enlarged to show texture.

The preferable method, and indeed the authoritative troubleshooting method for DNS resolution on Windows, would be to use `nslookup` to perform reverse lookups. For example, `nslookup 172.28.45.5`. You can explicitly set the server that you're querying against, and also scope your return record types down to only PTR records.

If you use `nslookup` to perform reverse queries from the same server and you get mixed responses, then something is wrong with DNS in a bad way. If for some reason you really, *really* want `ping -a` to be consistent, then you'll want to flush your resolver cache (`ipconfig /flushdns`), disable NetBIOS entirely (feels good, man), make sure nothing is in your hosts file, and then engage in somber prayer before each `ping -a` because I still wouldn't trust it 100%.

`nslookup` is good and wants to be your friend.